# String Collection Property on Model not Created in Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I've created a class called `Tag`.

```
public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TagId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<string> Synonyms { get; set; }
}
```

How do I get the `Synonyms` property into the database?

Do I have to create a model for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you would have to create a `Model`, perhaps do this:

```
public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TagId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Synonym> Synonyms { get; set; }
}
```

Then your Synonym Model:

```
public class Synonym
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int SynonymId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Tag"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int TagId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to either wrap it in an entity class

e.g.

```
public class Synonym
{
  int SynonymId {get; set;}
  string Synonym {get; set;}
}
```

or flatten your collection into a seperate string field

e.g:

```
public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TagId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SynStore {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<string> Synonyms 
{
    set { SynStore = String.Join(',', value);}
    get{ return SynStore.split(','); }
}
}
```